# What is the chibi-esque gathering at the end of each episode?

Tags: ro-kyu-bu

At the end of each episode of *Ro-Kyu-Bu!*, and sometimes during the episode content, the girls are seen talking to each other or to the audience in chibi form. Usually there is 8-bit music in the background, and the characters appear to be sprites (without animations).

[image]
[image]

Is this a game they're playing? Or, is it something more meta (like a representation of them talking by phone)? If it's a game, does it have a name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first episode of *Ro-Kyu-Bu! SS*, the girls are again shown in their chibi forms. It is then revealed that they are simply typing into their phones and computers as their conversation goes on.

[image]

Since they're doing this on flip phones, it seems unlikely that they're playing a game, despite the occasional "Now Loading" screen. The most likely conclusion is that the chibis are just a representation of each character chatting with the others, probably shown because it's more appealing than showing each girl on their personal computers.